# Remove Padding from MaterialUi grids

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, tsx

Im building a react project in which i need to display a few cards with content on them. I'm using the MaterialUi cards and in order to line them horizontally in different rows, I'm using the Material UI grids. However the issue that I have is that the Grid seems to have a lot of padding which makes the cards spaced out as if they are allergic to each other.

The code I am using is below:

```
export const ToolCards = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container spacing={1}  >
        <Grid item xs={3} >
          <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 250 }}>
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              alt="test-card1"
              height="200"
              image={img}/>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                test
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
              <Button>
                Learn More
              </Button>
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </Grid>

       <Grid container spacing={1}  >
        <Grid item xs={3} >
          <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 250 }}>
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              alt="test-card2"
              height="200"
              image={img}/>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                test
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
              <Button>
                Learn More
              </Button>
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      
     </Grid>
   </div>
```

The above example is for 2 cards but I have 5 cards, and the padding in between them seems to be quite large when the browser is in full screen

I have tried adding "container spacing" in the top most grid however it has not worked. I also tried adding padding to the top most div but that failed also.

Answer (score 0):

Set the spacing property value to 0. Ex: `<Grid container spacing={0}>` to remove the padding or just completely remove the spacing property. Ex: `<Grid container>`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried removing that but it makes no difference to the padding :/. Without the Grid all Card's get lined up in a single column with no bottom padding so i'm assuming the padding is coming from the grid!